# Shading and fading on same path using pgf and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, shading

Trying to mimic a titlepage in a word document.
I figured out how to do a custom shading, but can't figure out how to apply a fading (transparency) on top of it

Here is a MWE (except for the fading part).

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}


\begin{document}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{42,137,149}   
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{11,59,93}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshading}{100bp}{color(0cm)=(color1); color(16bp)=(color1); color(100bp)=(color2)}    
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshadingtransparent}{100bp}{color(0cm)=(pgftransparent!0); color(16bp)=(pgftransparent!0); color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!50)}

\pgfdeclarefading{fade1}{\pgfuseshading{myshadingtransparent}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{3cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3cm}{1.5cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfshadepath{myshading}{0}
\pgfsetfading{fade1}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By the way, do I really have to do everything with pgf, or is it partly possible using tikz instructions? I tried mixing the two but my shading would'nt apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the colors and the effect a bit. Here are two versions:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshading}{100bp}{color(0cm)=(blue); color(16bp)=(blue); color(80bp)=(blue!40!yellow); color(100bp)=(yellow)}    
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshadingtransparent}{100bp}{color(0cm)=(pgftransparent!0); color(16bp)=(pgftransparent!20); color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!100)}
\pgfdeclarefading{fade1}{\pgfuseshading{myshadingtransparent}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[shading=myshading,path fading=fade1] (0,0) -- +(90:2) -- +(30:2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And in the lower level version

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshading}{100bp}{color(0cm)=(blue); color(16bp)=(blue); color(80bp)=(blue!40!yellow); color(100bp)=(yellow)}    
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshadingtransparent}{100bp}{color(0cm)=(pgftransparent!0); color(16bp)=(pgftransparent!20); color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!100)}

\pgfdeclarefading{fade1}{\pgfuseshading{myshadingtransparent}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{3cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3cm}{1.5cm}}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfsetfadingforcurrentpath{fade1}{}
\pgfshadepath{myshading}{0}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for both anwser. I was not that far off.Any reason why applying `\pgfshadepath` before `\pgfsetfading` doesn't work?

Comment: @Snow Once the path is used it is thrown away. `shadepath` or `usepath` uses the path.

Comment: @Snow You should consider accepting the answer by clicking on the greyed out tick thing at the top left of the answer.

Comment: @cfr Done. I forgot !